# web site responsive only in mozilla

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have been looking at my media query for some time and i cannot figure out what mistake i have done in to it. The site is only responsive in mozilla browser.
Here goes my media query

```
@media only screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:728px) {
    #header {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #navr {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .shadow {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #bookmark {
        float: none;
        margin: 17px 43px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #leftbar-w {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin: -5px -8px 0 -7px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #jmslideshow img {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #rightbar-w {
        float: none;
        margin: 0 -13px;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #sidebar .module {
        border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .userdata {
        padding: 0;
    }
    #Kunena #ktab li, #Kunena #ktab div.moduletable ul.menu li {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

please help me

Comment: Please mention the issue that you are facing

Comment: site is only responsive in mozilla not in chrome, ie etc

Comment: So, what do you expect from us to be done. Do you want to make it responsive For Chrome and IE also ?

Comment: @Nehal What else could it be?

Comment: yes its been long time i have been looking at

Comment: If you have a test server, could you please host it there so we can see on LIVE how the issue appears.

Comment: Doesn't make much difference but try using `@media (max-width:728px){}` because practically no one would be using any screen below 320px

Comment: Please include the HTML you are using, as that will assist in debugging.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i finally figure out i forgot to include meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```